# Mic stand for sterling ST51 mic

Tags: microphone

Sorry for the n00b question.  Hopefully this is an appropriate place to post.

I recently bought a couple of mics.  1) a Sterling ST51, and 2) a MXL V900.  I gave the MXL to my brother for christmas because it came with a boom stand.  Curiously, I noticed that the adapter that came with the Sterling mic doesn't fit the boom stand.

I tried some googling around for types of mic stand adapters, without much luck.  I think I picked up on standard vs. european style, but I don't really know what that means.

Anyway, I would like to buy a stand for the Sterling mic, but I don't know what kind of stand to buy.  [Here](http://www.flickr.com/photos/mattheyan/5353100467/) is a picture of the adapter.  Please help if you can identify the style or any info on what kind of stand I can buy.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like an adapter to go from a standard tripod threading (like, for cameras) to standard threading for a microphone clip.

[image: Gitzo G1145 Bushing Microphone Adapter]

[http://www.amazon.com/Gitzo-G1145-Bushing-Microphone-Adapter/dp/B00023JDSU](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00023JDSU)

Comment: It turns out that it is in fact the adapter you mention.  It comes out of the rest of the adapter and it look like what is left may fit on the mic stand!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can always get a shock mount for it: [Shock Mount](http://compare.ebay.com/like/290402145383?ltyp=AllFixedPriceItemTypes&var=sbar&rvr_id=198123947911&crlp=1_263602_304662&UA=%3F*I%3F&GUID=12a1c30112c0a06c1b52cbe2ff8407d8&itemid=290402145383&ff4=263602_304662)

[image]